# Trying to prove (A ∩ B) − C = (A − C) ∩ (B − C)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Trying to prove $(A ∩ B) − C=(A − C) ∩ (B − C)$ Im stuck here on this problem:

$(A∩B)−C=\{x | x ∈ (A ∩ B)∧ x ∉ C\}$

$(A∩B)−C=\{x|(x ∈ A ∧ x ∈ B) ∧ x ∉ C\}$

$(A∩B)−C=\{x|(x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ C) \lor (x ∈ B ∧ x ∉ C)\}$

I'm stuck right about here because how do I change the or (v) sign to the intersection sign (∩).

Please don't link me to the other question like this, I had a typo in it.

Comment: then edit the question there. You have created like 3 times the same question. Up here says edit: My suggestion, do it in the other thread and delete this one.

Comment: edited it, can you help me out

Comment: Why did you change the "and" sign to an "or" sign.  That third line simply isn't true.  But it would have been if you hadn't  changed the sign. (P and Q)and S = (P and S) and (Q and S).  You'd be done if you did that.

Answer (score 1):

$$(A \cap B) - C = (A \cap B) \cap C^c = (A \cap C^c) \cap (B \cap C^c) = (A - C) \cap (B - C) $$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $A-C=A\cap C^{c}$. Hence:
\begin{align}
(A-C)\cap(B-C)&=(A\cap C^{c})\cap(B\cap C^{c})\\
&=(A\cap B)\cap C^{c}\\
&=(A\cap B)-C.
\end{align}
If you want to justify each step, use the three following facts about the relation of intersection $\cap$ on sets:

- It is associative (as a consequence of the associativity of the logical connective "and")
- It is commutative (as a consequence of the commutativity of the logical connective "and")
- For any set $S$, $S\cap S=S$ (such a relation is called "idempotent")